# How to match the build type of an Android Gradle project dependency?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have a project with 2 modules: `library` and `app`.

The `library` module is of course a library and only has `release` and `debug` build types.

The `app` module has 4 flavors as well as the `release` and `debug` build types, giving it a total of 8 build variants. It also declares a dependency on the `library` module like so:

`compile project(path:':library', configuration:'release')`

I'd like to be able to set the `library` config based on the app's build variant: `release` build variants should use the `release` version of the library and `debug` build variants should use the `debug` version of the library.

The obvious answer is to list each of the 8 variants and put the proper configuration and it'll work, but that's not the optimal answer: It's ugly and clutters the build script too much.

I've attempted a few approaches with `project.configurations.all{}` and `applicationVariants.all{}` but I couldn't find a definitive way to set the dependency configuration.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone still would be running into this (or similar) issue nowadays,  you would want to use `matchingFallbacks` to specify which resolved buildType or flavour to fallback to in case the library you depend on does not have matching configurations.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#resolve_matching_errors

By default though there should be a `debug` and `release` profile so to fix the OP question you would just need to remove the explicit configuration setting in the dependency declaration:

```
// forces release configuration on library
compile project(path:':library', configuration:'release')

// Allows gradle to match buildType from library to 
// what the current module's buildType is:
compile project(path:':library')
```

Snippets from the dev site in case it moves in the future (.kts):

```
// In the app's build.gradle file.
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Do not configure matchingFallbacks in the defaultConfig block.
        // Instead, you must specify fallbacks for a given product flavor in the
        // productFlavors block, as shown below.
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("debug") {}
        getByName("release") {}
        create("staging") {
            // Specifies a sorted list of fallback build types that the
            // plugin should try to use when a dependency does not include a
            // "staging" build type. You may specify as many fallbacks as you
            // like, and the plugin selects the first build type that's
            // available in the dependency.
            matchingFallbacks += listOf("debug", "qa", "release")
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions += "tier"
    productFlavors {
        create("paid") {
            dimension = "tier"
            // Because the dependency already includes a "paid" flavor in its
            // "tier" dimension, you don't need to provide a list of fallbacks
            // for the "paid" flavor.
        }
        create("free") {
            dimension = "tier"
            // Specifies a sorted list of fallback flavors that the plugin
            // should try to use when a dependency's matching dimension does
            // not include a "free" flavor. You may specify as many
            // fallbacks as you like, and the plugin selects the first flavor
            // that's available in the dependency's "tier" dimension.
            matchingFallbacks += listOf("demo", "trial")
        }
    }
}
```